# Этот выпуск не соответствует требованиям Google Play к 64-разрядным приложениям

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-play

**При загрузки приложения в Play Market появляется ошибка :**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Этот выпуск не соответствует требованиям Google Play к 64-разрядным приложениям*

*Следующие файлы APK или наборы App Bundle доступны для 64-разрядных устройств, но содержат только 32-разрядный нативный код: 13 и 14.*

*Включите в приложение 64-разрядный и 32-разрядный нативный код. Используйте формат публикации "Набор Android App Bundle", чтобы каждое устройство скачивало только соответствующий его архитектуре нативный код. Это поможет уменьшить общий размер приложения. [Подробнее…](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)*

**Ну я сразу решил пойти посмотреть на мануал по этому (ссылка сверху). И о чудо , там есть решение**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Первый раз мне это помогло , но потом стали выбивать ошибки**

**Вот мой скрин:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `но потом стали выбивать ошибки` какие?

Comment: @tym32167 Я уже писал выше.Первый раз когда я проделал эти манипуляции ошибка "Этот выпуск не соответствует требованиям Google Play к 64-разрядным приложениям" пропала.Потом я снова попытался загрузить таким же образом приложение , но уже как "внутренние тестирование".Здесь у меня снова появилась та же ошибка что и раньше ,хоть я и следовал указаниям от google play.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нашел решение 
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-and-google-play-64-bit-requirement.634936/
Нужно снять галочку поддержки платформ x86

Comment: Ответ помог,спасибо.

Comment: спасибо, почти целый день пытался найти ошибку

Comment: Если снять галочку х86, то приложение будет недоступно для многих устройств